# Why do tags show the vote count for answers only but the tag count for both Q's and A's?

Tags: discussion, tags, badges

When you view your tags on your user page, each tag has a number to the left - that's the total number of votes for all the *answers* you've given in that tag. To the right is another number - that's the total number of questions **and** answers you've submitted for that tag. Why the inconsistency?

I suspect that the vote count is there primarily because of [tag badges](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/badges?tab=tags), and if I'm right, it makes it even weirder. A tag badge requires a certain number of votes (100, 400, or 1000) on a certain amount of answers (20, 80, 200). So why show the vote count only for answers, and the tag count for both questions and answers?

Answer (score 3):

I honestly can't say for sure *why* it's this way...

But it's worth noting that the two numbers came into existence separately, with the post count shown first, and the score [added later](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73307/how-can-i-get-my-reputation-and-votes-per-tag).

That said, I actually didn't realize it was answers-only. Granted, I tend to have a lot more answers than I do questions, and your tag-badge theory makes sense... But it strikes me as a bit odd too.

Note that if you hover over the first number, you'll get a little pop-up that gives a nice breakout of posts and scores by post type. This is probably a lot more useful.

Comment: So is this [meta-tag:status-by-design]?

Comment: I think that if this is going to stay this way, there should be an explanation somewhere on the user page that explains what each number refers to.